# Why the switch statement does not enter to the case 2?

Tags: java, switch-statement

thank you for read my question.
I don´t have any problem with the compiler, and when I run the program the case 1 works well but the case 2 do not work, When I try to use it the program go back to the main menu. than you for your help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opcion=0;
    double[][] m;

    do{

        m=new double[0][0];
        opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"El programa permite:\n1.Ingresar Inventario\n2.Calcular Inventario\n3.Salir"));
        switch(opcion){
            case 1: 


                m=Metodos.LLenarMatriz();
                Metodos.Imprimir(m);

            break;

            case 2:

                double[][] r=Metodos.CalcularInventario(m);
                Metodos.Imprimir(r);
            break;    
        }

    }
    while(opcion!=3);


    }

}
```

Here are two methods:

```
public static double[][] CalcularInventario (double[][] x){

    double fac,n=0;
    int filx;
    filx=x.length;
    double [][] c=new double[filx][3];
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<x[i].length;j++){
            c[i][j]=x[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++)
    {
        fac=x[i][0];


        n=fac*c[i][1];
        c[i][2]=n;



    } 

    return c; 
}
```

and

```
public static void Imprimir(double[][] m){

    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++){

            System.out.print(m[i][j]+"|");

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by option 2 does not work? Specific output or examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is where using a debugger would help debug your code but.

```
m=new double[0][0];
```

so the matrix is empty.

```
int filx;
filx=x.length;
double [][] c=new double[filx][3];
```

and `x.length` is 0 so `c` is empty.

```
for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    System.out.print("\n");
```

but `m.length` is still 0 so it doesn't print anything.

I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to understand at what point it isn't doing what you expected. I also suggest you use the formatter in your IDe to make your code easier to read.